# Xamarin - How should I handle UI state changes in a Command prior to an async API call

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I typically use the Command pattern with Xamarin forms. Recently the UIs I have been working on involve commands that call a remote API, and while they do so they indicate that something is going on in a number of ways. For example, an ActivityIndicator should start to spin, when the API call returns the page should disable the button, etc.

What I would intuitively code up is an async ICommand like this:

```
VerifyCodeCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                await VerifyCode(_email,_code);
            });
```

while in the VerifyCode function I would change the property bound to the IsRunning property of the `ActivityIndicator` to true,  `await` the API call, then on completion change the IsRunning/Visible of the `ActivityIndicator` back to false. 
For example like this:
Another example is showing an API failed state (eg: red warnings) and then resetting it immediately before the API call.

Unfortunately this does not work, and neither does setting the bound property on `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, as (presumably) the ICommand is holding the UI thread (?) . What I do with this simple case is set the property to `true` in the command, then `Task.Run` the remainder of the function body, i.e. the API call and resetting the indicator, like this:

```
 Sending = true;

            (VerifyCodeCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();

            await Task.Run(async () =>

            {

                try

                {

                  // await api call here

                }

                catch (Exception ex)

                {

                    App.TrackError(ex, "Login", "VerifyCode API call failed.");

                }

                finally

                {

                    Sending = false;

                    (VerifyCodeCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();

                }

            });







        }
```

Is this approach necessary or am I missing some area of functionality in Xamarin (Forms)? If it is always necessary, to update the UI this way, what would be a sensible approach for 'patternising' this? For example, should Commands always have two actual lambdas, one for initial UI state set up, one for background invocation? Why is it that a simple single threaded async approach does not work here - the API call is being awaited after all.

I suppose why question distills down to: why is it that invoking an async API call with await on the main thread appears as though the main thread is not being freed to do UI updates (this seems like Xamarin UI lifecycle is introducing some limitation) and what is the standard solution for this?

Comment: Please mark sure the IsRunning property you updated and the one bound to the ActivityIndicator are the same. You could add a break point to check that. For this feature, you could also use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to do the work.

Comment: @y3z1 The issue is not the property name - it's that nothing happens unless the async API call is pushed onto a new thread with Task.Run

Comment: Api calling may takes a long time, use the `await Task.Run` to do the time-consuming work in a non-ui thread, which can make the following steps work properly.

Comment: OK so after all this was just down to the API call running synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're issue is that you're over laying an await Task onto the asynchronous nature of the Command.

As an example from a current app:
All of my ViewModels have a property `bool IsBusy`

Property `public ICommand RefreshStoredDataCommand {get;}`

In the constructor : `RefreshStoredDataCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteRefreshDataCommand(), () => !IsBusy);`

```
private async Task ExecuteRefreshDataCommand()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    try
    {
      //Long calls to asynchronous processes
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ProjectViewModel:ExecuteRefreshDataCommand exception{e.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }

}
```

For the example shown I have in my View a `ListView` control where I set

```
RefreshCommand ="{Binding RefreshStoredDataCommand}"
IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Obviously for your code you'd bind your activity indicator instead.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but using the above code, the ActivityIndicator does not update. I have actually tested this and where you have "//Long calls to async process" , if that is not a Task.Run( ()=> //long call) to spawn a new thread, then the UI does not update. I can't understand why. I was under the impression that the main thread would have been freed up by awaiting the async task, so that the UI could update, but nope.

Comment: The area commented out where I have "long calls to asynchronous tasks is where I have calls to my remote http database access tasks. The cycle indicator for the `ListView` definitely appears and cycles whilst the task is in progress. I'll check with activity indicator. Did you remember to trigger `NotifyPropertyChanged` when changing the `IsBusy` value?

Comment: yeah all that works if the //long calls part is Task.Run. So, no trivial errors there like NotifyPropertyChanges or misnamed properties. Literally, change from await DoSomething() to await Task.Run(()=>DoSomething and it works.

Comment: Sorry - I have found the problem. I feel I have wasted your time. The actual call I had was running synchronously after all. I should basically delete my question. I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @Frank no problem.